# ASP.NET URL Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, url-routing

How can I make my URL like: `www.mydomain.com/JohnSmith`

Instead of: `www.mydomain.com/Customers/JohnSmith`

This is my global.asax file

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("Customers", "Customers", "~/Customers.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("CustomerDetails", "Customers/{CustomerName}", "~/CustomerDetails.aspx");
}
```

Comment: web forms or mvc?

Comment: Based on OP's code - WebForms

Comment: it is web forms

Comment: Keep in mind if you ever have a customer that has a name of "Default" or "About" or something else like that, you could have issues with your routing scheme. When planning URL's, this sort of thing takes special thought.

Comment: @mason well thank you for this advice, i will keep it in my mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in constraints to the MapPageRoute, in particular, this is the signature:

```
public Route MapPageRoute(
    string routeName,
    string routeUrl,
    string physicalFile,
    bool checkPhysicalUrlAccess,
    RouteValueDictionary defaults,
    RouteValueDictionary constraints,
    RouteValueDictionary dataTokens
)
```

And here's what you need:

```
static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    //rest of routes...
    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "CustomerDetails", 
        "{CustomerName}", 
        "~/CustomerDetails.aspx", 
        true, 
        null, 
        new RouteValueDictionary { {"CustomerName", @"\w+" } },
        null);
}
```

Comment: when i added the above constraints in global.asax i got error

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: The first block of code is just the method signature for `.MapPageRoute()`that I'm using. I included it for educational purposes of what each parameter is doing. Useful in this context, since Uncle Bob didn't write ASP.NET.

Comment: Oh... I had a missing comma and a copy paste error in the method... that's probably what your error was.

Answer (score 0):

I have been dabbling in ASP.NET and I ran into these pages...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx